# Направление стрелок в графе

Tags: графы

Разве здесь стрелки не должны идти в обратном направлении? Мы же сначала просыпаемся, потом чистим зубы, а после завтракаем. На рисунке кажется, будто мы сначала завтракаем, потом чистим зубы, а после просыпаемся.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Книга: "грокаем алгоритмы"

Comment: Да, стрелки должны быть перевёрнуты.

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn, как-то не верится, что такая грубая опечатка может быть в такой простой и популярной книге

Comment: Просто игнорируйте направление стрелок в данной блок-схеме. Правила таких схем гласят, что они читаются слева-направо, или сверху вниз.

Comment: В комментарии на изображении указан верный порядок

Comment: Все относительно. Стрелки могут обозначать как "у А потомок Б" так и "у Б предок А". Главное чтобы правило последовательно и однообразно применялось ) Но в целом, да, стрелки по ходу процесса более привычны и чаще используются.

Comment: Это стрелки-зависимости. Чтобы позавтракать, надо почистить зубы. Чтобы почистить зубы или принять душ, надо проснуться. В таком графе вы задаёте цель - завтрак и узнаёте какие пререквизиты-зависимости есть у этой цели - чистка зубов в сознательном состоянии. Так устроен makefile например.